# How to make sure the predicted ratio is always greater than 0 in linear regression

Tags: regression, linear

I created a linear regression model to predict the utilization ratio (between 0 and 1) of a customer. When I used this model to score my out of time population, I found out negative predicted values. How can I make sure the predicted value always between 0 and 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Simplest solution is to convert 0 to 1 region into a real line, e.g. by using the logistic function (regression), logit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use linear regression. Depending on what data you have and exactly what you are trying to do, either logistic regression or beta regression might be right.

Comment: I looked up the beta regression. It seems a good option. Need to read more about about to setup the parameters required.